# How to use set_include_path so that it actually works?

Tags: php, include

I'm currently working on a website which has to write data into a google spreadsheet. To do so I had to download the Zend framework and I'm about to install it. The Google developer website tells me to:

*"If you don't have shell access to your server and can't modify or create .htaccess files that you can always use the set_include_path function. Note that you may already have some value set for your include_path so it may be a good idea to follow the model below to append the new values, instead of overwriting the entire path:"*

```
$clientLibraryPath = '/path/to/ZendGdata/library';
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientLibraryPath);
```

So here is what I did:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/ZendGdata-2.5.3/library");
```

This was the result:

```
/usr/local/reserved:/sites/xxxxx.xxx/www/ZendGdata-2.5.3/library
```

Why does it return the wrong value and more important; what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Tried `DEFINE("PATH_SEPARATOR", "/");`?

Comment: Try over-writing with `set_include_path("/usr/local/reserved/sites/xxxxx.xxx/www/ZendGdata-2.5.3/library");`? Bad practice in long term but it would be interesting if it worked